# Flask-Dance @oauth_authorized.connect_via() method never executes when logging in

Tags: flask, google-oauth, flask-login

I am using the Flask-Dance library to login users with Google. I am able to successfully authenticate users but the code under @oauth_authorized.connect_via(google_blueprint) never executes. I tried renaming some of the blueprints/methods but nothing seems to work. I know that this issue is specific to google login because I tried this same exact code with twitter and github and everything worked perfectly. Is there a specific concept about google login that I am missing?

Code:

```
google_blueprint = make_google_blueprint(client_id='CLIENT_ID_HERE',client_secret='SECRET_HERE')
app.register_blueprint(google_blueprint,url_prefix='/google_login')
google_blueprint.backend = SQLAlchemyBackend(OAuth, db.session,user=current_user,user_required=False)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
    payed = db.Column(db.Boolean)
class OAuth(OAuthConsumerMixin, db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey(User.id))
    user = db.relationship(User)

@app.route('/google')
def google_login():
    if not google.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for('google.login'))
    return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

@oauth_authorized.connect_via(google_blueprint)
def google_is_logged_in(blueprint,token):
    global paying_dude
    account_info = blueprint.session.get('/user')
    if account_info.ok:
        account_info_json = account_info.json()
        username = account_info_json['first_name']
        query = User.query.filter_by(username=username)
        try:
            user=query.one()
        except NoResultFound:
            user = User(username=username,payed=False)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            paying_dude = username
            return redirect(url_for('pay'))
        if user.payed:
            login_user(user)
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
        return redirect(url_for('pay'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

`account_info = blueprint.session.get('/user')`

to

`account_info = blueprint.session.get('/oauth2/v2/userinfo')`

If you are keen you can review my working gist here:

https://gist.github.com/ericcgu/6eae82aa99a37e6a4369cd5513fc4a54